# Accessing web table using Python - NIST website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, mechanize, urllib

I am trying to access a table from the NIST website here:
http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/tab3.html

Assume that I click the element zinc. I would like to retrieve the information for Energy, u/p and u[en]/p into 3 columns of a table using python 2.7.

I am beginning to learn BeautifulSoup and Mechanize. However, I am finding it hard to identify a clear pattern in the HTML code relating to the table on this site.

What I am looking for is some way to something like this:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page=mech.open("http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/tab3.html")
html = page.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

My thought was to try:

```
table = soup.find("table",...)
```

The ... above would be some identifier. I can't find a clear identifier on the NIST website above.

How would I be able to import this table using python 2.7?

EDIT: Is it possible to put these 3 columns in a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you well,
**Try this**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

respond = requests.get("http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ElemTab/z30.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(respond.text)
l = soup.find('table').find('table').find_all('tr')
for i in range(3 , len(l)):
    print l[i].get_text()
```

**Edit:**
Other way (Getting ASCII column) and put rows to the list l:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

respond = requests.get("http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ElemTab/z30.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(respond.text)
l = soup.find('table').find('pre').get_text()[145:].split("\n")
print l
```

Comment: CodeNinja: This appears to be printing the information to the screen. I have two questions: a. Could you explain the last three lines in detail? b. Is it possible to put this in a table instead of printing to a screen?

Comment: I edited my answer. To understand find() arguments you need to see the html tree.

Comment: CodeNinja: The edit did not work out. It gives this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/test3.py", line 7, in <module>
    l = soup.find('table').find('pre').get_text()[145:].split("\n")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: For your second script (getting the ASCII table), why did you use 145?

Comment: `soup.find('table').find('pre').get_text()` returns the string with all data (ASCII format table). We don't need first 145 characters so we use [145:]. Try use code without [145:] to figure out what is in first 145 chars.